# How to join tables with a LIKE condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, loops, sql-server-2008

Table a:

```
id
a
b
c
```

Table b:

```
a-1
a-2
a-3
b-1
b-2
b-3
```

How can I retrive data from table b on the basis of the id column in table a?

A like condition does not seem to work.

Comment: The question is really hard to understand as its currently phrased. Help us help you by [edit]ing the question and adding some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it.

Comment: Sample data and desired results *as text tables* would clarify what you want to do.  Also, why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?  Also, what is your current query?

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're looking for

```
create table tblA(id varchar(10))
create table tblB(id varchar(10))

insert tblA values ('a'),('b'),('c')
insert tblB values ('a-1'),('a-2'),('a-3'),('b-1'),('b-2'),('b-3')

select * from tblA join tblB on tblB.id like tblA.id + '%'
```

Output

```
id  id
a   a-1
a   a-2
a   a-3
b   b-1
b   b-2
b   b-3
```